# How can I structure this while loop so that it checks for two conditions and also termaintes it when necessary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code here

```
def step(self, joint_values):
    """
    Step function which publishes actions and evaluates state/reward.

    Args:
        action: takes an action (Int) as input. Value from 0-6

    Returns:
        State after executed action, reward after executed action and done, 
        which is a bool, True or False depending on if episode is done.
    """
    self.iterator += 1

    self._coll = self.observation_callback_collision()
    coll_force = self._coll.wrench.force.x

    if coll_force >= 150 or coll_force <= -150:
        self.reset_robot2.call()
        self.reward_coll = -0.5
        self.collided += 1
        print("#############Collision##############")
        rospy.sleep(1)

    #print("ACTION", joint_values)
    else:
        i = 0
        while i<=1000:
            self.traj.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
            action = JointTrajectoryPoint()
            action.positions = joint_values
            #print("W", action.positions)
            action.time_from_start = rospy.Duration(0.7)
            self.traj.points = []
            self.traj.points.append(action)
            #rospy.sleep(4.5)
            self.action_pub.publish(self.traj)

            i +=0.1
```

If you see here what I am trying to achieve is, whenever the step function is called it checks for the if condition (if it is true then it resets the robot or else it activates the while loop). The problem is when RL agent chooses a action "joint_values" such that when the step function is called, the if con
is checked only once and if the action chosen by the agent is not good the robot goes in collision.

what I want is that when the step function is called the while loop **while i<= 1000** which terminates at i += 1, also checks every time for the collision i.e. **coll_force >= 150 or coll_force <= -150:** and if the collision exceeds the limits it stops publishing the action (self.action_pub.publish(self.traj)) and resets the robot (self.reset_robot2.call()).

I know its bit confusing but what I am trying to do is something like this,

```
def step(self, joint_values):

    self.iterator += 1

    self._coll = self.observation_callback_collision()
    coll_force = self._coll.wrench.force.x


    while i<=1000:
      if coll_force >= 150 or coll_force <= -150:
            self.reset_robot2.call()
            self.reward_coll = -0.5
            self.collided += 1
            print("#############Collision##############")
            rospy.sleep(1)

      else:
            self.traj.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
            action = JointTrajectoryPoint()
            action.positions = joint_values
            #print("W", action.positions)
            action.time_from_start = rospy.Duration(0.7)
            self.traj.points = []
            self.traj.points.append(action)
            self.action_pub.publish(self.traj)

      i +=0.1
```

But this here doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: Hello. What is the problem with your solution?

Comment: the problem is then when I run it, if the "if" condition is true then it continuously loops in the if condition itself, that is the robot resets a couple of times, but what i want is just reset the robot once

Comment: In a second code but `break` at the end of the first if statement. Otherwise it will got to that if 10000 times.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you want to check for multiple conditions in a loop, you can use an accumulated flag that indicates if the loop should terminate. There are other options, such as `break` or setting `i` to a value outside the range, but for readability it might be best to use the flag:

```py
is_running = True
while is_running:
    # do stuff here, calculate coll_force
    i += 0.1
    is_running = is_running and (coll_force > -150 and coll_force < 150)
    is_running = is_running and i <= 1000
```

This way you can use as many conditions as you like, each conditions can be handled seperately from the others and you have an obvious place where you can read the code that checks the conditions, namely at the end of the loop block.

Answer (score 1):

I like Etienne's answer. And would advise you to structure your function as he suggests. Alternatively, here is a modification to your first attempt that should do exactly what you want it to do.

- I added a `reset_one` state that acts as a second condition to be met by your `if` statement. If the `if` has been called once, it will be set to true and will disallow the `if` catch, only allowing the `else` to be called.
- Alternatively you can use the `reset_count` variable I have commented out if you allow a certain amount of resets.

```py
def step(self, joint_values):
    self.iterator += 1

    self._coll = self.observation_callback_collision()
    coll_force = self._coll.wrench.force.x

    # Add has_been_reset boolean state.
    reset_once = False
    # reset_count = 0  # Alternative.

    while i <= 1000:

        # Added second condition. Modify condition if you allow a certain
        # amount of resets during the while loop. Here it allows the if
        # condition to be triggered ONCE (Use reset_count <= n_allowed
        # alternatively)
        if (coll_force >= 150 or coll_force <= -150) and not reset_once:
            self.reset_robot2.call()
            self.reward_coll = -0.5
            self.collided += 1
            print("#############Collision##############")
            rospy.sleep(1)

            reset_once = True  # <--------------
            # reset_count += 1   # <-- Alternative

        else:
            self.traj.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
            action = JointTrajectoryPoint()
            action.positions = joint_values
            # print("W", action.positions)
            action.time_from_start = rospy.Duration(0.7)
            self.traj.points = []
            self.traj.points.append(action)
            self.action_pub.publish(self.traj)

        i += 0.1
```

Edit: Typo*